# Consuming JSON directly to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, json

I have a JSON API with a token information that I want to integrate with ArcGIS Online to create a heatmap. It's a news feed API that gives latitude, longitude, country, news in brief and news in detail.

I am unable to find a way to directly use the API to consume the JSON. Is there a way I can use the JSON directly or consume it in ArcGIS Server without using the Geoevent Server(used for real-time GIS)?